# QT QPixmap load image defeat

Tags: qt, qpixmap

```
    qDebug() << QFileInfo(":/images/123.jpg").exists();

    QPixmap myPix;
    myPix.load(":/images/123.jpg");

    if(myPix.isNull())
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to load image" ;
    }
```

```
true
Failed to load image
```

Here is the code and output. It bothers me a lot of time.

Comment: what is the output of: `QImageReader reader(":/images/123.jpg"); 
QImage img = reader.read() 
if(img.isNull())
{
    qDebug() << reader.errorString();
}`

Comment: @eyllanesc It's   "Unable to read image data"

Comment: So it's probably not an image, maybe it's a corrupt file or some other type of file.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you I change another image can be read .I changed its extend file name early. I thought this image can be displayed by Windows and it also can be read by QPixmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it look like the res is corrupt... and cant be loaded.

you should verify that the res is loaded properly:

```
if(myPix.load(":/images/123.jpg"))
{
    ....
}
```

like in the doc stated (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#load):

> Loads a pixmap from the file with the given fileName. Returns true if the pixmap was successfully loaded; otherwise invalidates the pixmap and returns false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed another image can be read.